# how to determine if a point is inside a polygon using geojson and shapely

Tags: python, polygon, geojson, shapely

I am hoping to create a region on a map and be able to automatically determine if points (coordinates) are inside that region. I'm using a geojson file of the entire US and coordinates for New York City for this example.

Geojson: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json

I have read the shapely documentation and just can't figure out why my results are returning False. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape, GeometryCollection, Point

with open('USA.geo.json', 'r') as f:
    js = json.load(f)

point = Point(40.712776, -74.005974)

for feature in js['features']:

    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])

    if polygon.contains(point):
        print ('Found containing polygon:', feature)
```

I'm hoping to print the contained coordinates, but nothing is printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to swap the values of the `Point()` around:

```
point = Point(-74.005974, 40.712776)
```

The dataset you're using has the longitude first and the latitude second in their coordinates.